# MySQL INSERT INTO tables with foreign key speed is very slow

Tags: mysql, grails, insert

I'm trying to insert (from postgres via grails) about 10 millions records into a table with a primary key and 2 foreign keys. If I keep the all primary and foreign keys and the indexes automatically generated along with these keys, it'll take about 7.5 hours to complete. If I drop all the keys and indexes before the inserts, it'll take only 10 minutes to executes all the inserts. But when I used ALTER TABLE to add the keys back in, it took forever (more than 7 hours) to perform. Is there a way to improve the performance?

The concept table that this table linked to has about 1 million records.

Here's the CREATE TABLE statement:

```
CREATE TABLE `concept_relationship` (
  `concept_id_1` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `concept_id_2` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `relationship_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `valid_start_date` date NOT NULL,
  `valid_end_date` date NOT NULL DEFAULT '2099-12-31',
  `invalid_reason` char(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`concept_id_1`,`concept_id_2`,`relationship_id`),
  KEY `concept_id_1` (`concept_id_1`),
  KEY `concept_id_2` (`concept_id_2`),
  KEY `relationship_id` (`relationship_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_CONCEPT_REL_child` FOREIGN KEY (`concept_id_2`) REFERENCES `concept` (`concept_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_CONCEPT_REL_Parent` FOREIGN KEY (`concept_id_1`) REFERENCES `concept` (`concept_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_CONCEPT_REL_REL_TYPE` FOREIGN KEY (`relationship_id`) REFERENCES `relationship` (`relationship_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the index `concept_id_1` is not needed.  The primary key covers this index entirely.

My suggestion is to create the table without the keys or foreign references, except for the primary key.  When you insert into the table, be sure that the input data is sorted by the keys of the primary key.  Then add back the other keys with explicit index creation:

```
create index concept_relationship_idx1 on concept_relationship(concept_id_1);
```

And so on.

If this doesn't work efficiently, then reconsider the primary key.  The data is actually ordered by the primary key, which can be computationally intensive for inserts.  Add an auto-incremented primary key.  Insert the data.  Then create a `unique` index for what is now the primary key, and indexes for the other keys.

Comment: The index concept_id_1 is automatically generated along with the foreign key constraint. You can't drop the index without dropping the constraint. Keeping the primary key also impacted the performance. I did try that without sorting the input query. I'll try sorting the input query. The primary combination key can't be changed. This is table from a fixed data model.

Comment: consider multithreading the insert with `@Transactional` as well keeping the above comment as input.

Comment: UPDATE: Inserting into table with primary key only took a short time to complete (15 minutes). However, creating the secondary index on concept_id_2 still took a long time to run (still running). When I tried creating the foreign key before creating the index, the performance was horrible. I don't know if multithreading is a good idea because, how will the index be built when multiple threads insert into a table at the same time? Any other thoughts?